# python: Converting code to a class

Tags: python, class

I am just learning python and jumping into classes. I have been using the following code for a simple stopwatch that I found.  I now want to create a class with this code. I will have 1-4 timers on the screen at any one time. I need to start them all at the same time but end each timer independently.  I am still plugging away at this but any help would be much appreciated.

```
import Tkinter as tk

def update_timeText():
     if (state):
    global timer
    timer[2] += 1

    if (timer[2] >= 100):
        timer[2] = 0
        timer[1] += 1
    if (timer[1] >= 60):
        timer[0] += 1
        timer[1] = 0
    timeString = pattern.format(timer[0], timer[1], timer[2])
    timeText.configure(text=timeString)
root.after(10, update_timeText)

def start():
    global state
    state = True

def pause():
    global state
    state = False

def reset():
    global timer
    timer = [0, 0, 0]
    timeText.configure(text='00:00:00')

def exist():
    root.destroy()

state = False

root = tk.Tk()
root.wm_title('Simple Kitchen Timer Example')

timer = [0, 0, 0]
pattern = '{0:02d}:{1:02d}:{2:02d}'

timeText = tk.Label(root, text="00:00:00", font=("Helvetica", 150))
timeText.pack()

startButton = tk.Button(root, text='Start', command=start)
startButton.pack()

pauseButton = tk.Button(root, text='Pause', command=pause)
pauseButton.pack()

resetButton = tk.Button(root, text='Reset', command=reset)
resetButton.pack()

quitButton = tk.Button(root, text='Quit', command=exist)
quitButton.pack()
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Sorry, how to convert the following to a class so I can have multiple timers at the same time and stop according independently.

Comment: Please try it yourself first.  We don't write code to spec here.  We will help you if you get stuck on a specific problem.

Comment: Thanks. I am in the process right now. I will try to post where I am stuck yet tonight.

Comment: Essentially you need to turn all the globals into instance variables (self.this, self.that, self.theother, ...), and their initializations need to happen in method `__init__`.  All functions can become methods by indenting them into your `class` statement, adding `self` as the first argument, and of course accessing and/or setting the instance variables instead of the globals.  Go for it -- and show us where you're stuck should you get stuck!-)

Comment: Alex, the __init__ stumped me but thanks for mentioning that since it was the final part I needed to figure out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a class simply try this:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class StopWatch(object):  # sub-class the object class maybe 

    def update_timeText(self):
        #your code logic...

    def start(self):
        #your code logic...

    #etc...


 #the rest of your functions are the same 
 #just specify the 'self' Python keyword before any other arguments in the function. :D
```

Let me know if this works. :D

Comment: Thanks for the help. This plus the comments from Alex helped me figure this all except one last feature. I will try to post the example.

Comment: Here is my solution.  What do you think? Is there anything you might streamline and improve upon?  The amount of self.  I used makes me think something is not right.

Comment: Hi Husar. I am glad this helped man. :D To improve your code you could create arguments/parameters to the init function/method that creates your object. So it would look something like: `def __init__(self, pattern= '{0:02d}:{1:02d}:{2:02d}', state = 'False', timeText='tk.Label(root, text='00:00:01', font=("Helvetica", 15))` and so on. This will give your object some default characteristics and also allow you to specify new values for one, none, or all of these parameter local variables. :D This way you can create different types of StopWatches from the same class.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. It took me so long to get my head around the class creation of this. Any ideas for improving this?

```
import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.wm_title('Stopwatch Class')
root.geometry("300x350")


class StopWatch(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.pattern = '{0:02d}:{1:02d}:{2:02d}'
        self.timer = [0, 0, 0]
        self.state = False
        self.timeText = tk.Label(root, text='00:00:01', font=("Helvetica", 15))
        self.timeText.pack()
        self.startButton = tk.Button(root, text='Start', command=self.start)
        self.startButton.pack()
        self.resetButton = tk.Button(root, text='Reset', command=self.reset)
        self.resetButton.pack()
        self.pauseButton = tk.Button(root, text='Pause', command=self.pause)
        self.pauseButton.pack()

    def update_timeText(self):

        if (self.state):
           self.timer[2] += 1

        if (self.timer[2] >= 100):
            self.timer[2] = 0
            self.timer[1] += 1
        if (self.timer[1] >= 60):
            self.timer[0] += 1
            self.timer[1] = 0
        self.timeString = self.pattern.format(self.timer[0], self.timer[1], self.timer[2])
        self.timeText.configure(text=self.timeString)
    root.after(10, self.update_timeText)

    def start(self):
        self.state = True

    def pause(self):
        self.state = False

    def reset(self):
        self.timer = [0, 0, 0]
        self.timeText.configure(text='00:00:00')

# create a new stopwatch
swatch1 = StopWatch()
swatch1.update_timeText()

# create a new stopwatch
swatch2 = StopWatch()
swatch2.update_timeText()

# create a new stopwatch
swatch3 = StopWatch()
swatch3.update_timeText()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Well, I was so focused on the code I did not realize that is not accurate at all.  The timers are way slow.  Any idea why it is not accurate?

Comment: Not sure why it is not accurate on the time. There is a module called `time` in python though that you could use. `import time; t = time.time()` gives the current time in seconds since the UNIX epoch or something. `import time; time.asctime()` gives a more readable time with the date and day of the week, etc. Hope this helps. :D